# Open an external form into current access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

Sorry for any errors, I translated it on Google, thank you.
Suppose I have an access database Database2.accdb that I compile and convert to Database2.accde and that I also have another Database1.mda that works as a plugin. This Database1.mda plugin is not added to the VBA project as a reference when Database2.accde is runing because is compiled. What I need then is from running Database2.accde to open a Database1.mda form and have it displayed on the Database2.accde screen. In a button on a form I call the external form in these ways and nothing, here is my code. Can you help me? Thanks

```
Private Sub btnMostrarFormularioExterno_Click()
    ' Abre la base de datos externa
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Dim app As Object
    Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\AA.mda", False
    app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Formulario2", acDialog
'show only one form
    For Each frm In Forms
        MsgBox frm.Name
    Next frm

    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Never heard of anything like this. Very much doubt what you describe is possible. I tested your code. Second db opens in its own application window. The loop on Forms does not iterate. Use `For Each frm In app.Forms`. Have you set breakpoint and step debugged?

Comment: yes i set it and confirmed that the external .mda was opened because a .ldb extension is created. Maybe my English is not good and can't explain the problem well but I have seen .accde projects that open when necessary forms from another .mda database and show them as a tab or form in the main window

Comment: Well, certainly wouldn't involve automation code as you posted. Might involve an OLEObjectFrame or WebBrowser control.